# NodeSet exception while using agilitypack

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

```
private void ShowStatistics_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
        doc = hw.Load("http://www.gamerankings.com/browse.html");
        HtmlNodeCollection nodes= doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a/");
        string result = "";
        foreach (var item in nodes)
        {
            result += item.InnerText+Environment.NewLine;
        }
        Info.ItemsSource = result;

    }
```

By pressing the button i want to get information from the webpage in a textbox called Info.
After pressing the button I get an exception saying that the result of expression should be NodeSet, what should I do? I'm using agility pack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XPATH is wrong. You can use this instead if you want to get all hyperlink elements

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a");
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Hung Cao, you can actually shorten this/work around:

```
foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("Selector here")){
    //your code here
}
```